# How does one creates a raster layer from SQL Server in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I want to implement a weather layer that displays temperatures from -40 to 40 degress in a map using GeoServer. I got an SQL Server table that looks something like:

```sql
create table temperature (id int identity primary key, geom geometry, temperature float)
```

Geom contains a Point for which a given temperature measure is applicable. I have added the table as layer in GeoServer but i'm stuck to actually be able to render it. Right now, the best i get is a big red square :D So, it seems like it renders as a pure point, and not a raster.

How does one creates correct bindings etc for the raster to be displayed nicely?

Is it done on SLD level or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `BarnesSurface` transformation as described in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304729/creating-contours-via-sld-using-the-barnes-surface-interpolation-in-geoserver). But since the transformation will be carried out each and every time the map is displayed it would be more efficient to rasterize the points once and then use that raster in GeoServer.

Comment: You're right, it's a bit too much to do this on the fly. Thanks!